# Error when building gccgo go1: error: '-fsplit-stack' currently only supported on GNU/Linux

Tags: go, gcc, makefile, build, compilation

My linux version when `uname -a` is

```
 Linux porteus 4.16.3-porteus #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 21 12:42:52 Local time zone must be set-- x86_64 AMD A6-7480 Radeon R5, 8 Compute Cores 2C+6G AuthenticAMD GNU/Linux
```

I am currently compiling gccgo from source (from the gcc 10.2 source tarball) on my machine using this configuration:

```
../configure --prefix=/usr \
 --libdir=/usr/lib64 \
--mandir=/usr/man \
--infodir=/usr/info \
--enable-shared --enable-static \
--disable-bootstrap --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libunwind-exceptions \
--enable-languages=go,lto --enable-libgomp --enable-lto --enable-threads=posix \
--enable-checking=release --enable-tls --enable-libssp \
--with-gmp-include=/tmp/gcc/include --with-gmp-lib=/tmp/gcc/lib64 \
--with-mpfr-include=/tmp/gcc/include --with-mpfr-lib=/tmp/gcc/lib64 \
--with-mpc-include=/tmp/gcc/include --with-mpc-lib=/tmp/gcc/lib64 \
--with-isl-include=/tmp/gcc/include --with-isl-lib=/tmp/gcc/lib64 \
--with-fpmath=sse --verbose --with-arch-directory=amd64 --disable-gtktest \
--disable-multilib --target=x86_64-slackware-linux --build=x86_64-slackware-linux \
--host=x86_64-slackware-linux --program-suffix=-go-10.2
```

Now when running `make -j2`, I kept getting this error (took lots of minutes to show):

```
=== log on terminal cut to shorten ===
/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build/./gcc/gccgo -B/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ -B/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/lib/ -isystem /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo -L ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo/.libs -o go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/alldocs.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/go11.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/go/main.go ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo/libgotool.a  
/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build/./gcc/gccgo -B/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ -B/usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/lib/ -isystem /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-slackware-linux/sys-include   -g -O2 -I ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -L ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo -L ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo/.libs -o gofmt ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/doc.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/gofmt.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/internal.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/rewrite.go ../../gotools/../libgo/go/cmd/gofmt/simplify.go ../x86_64-slackware-linux/libgo/libgotool.a  
go1: error: ‘-fsplit-stack’ currently only supported on GNU/Linux
go1: error: ‘-fsplit-stack’ is not supported by this compiler configuration
go1: error: ‘-fsplit-stack’ currently only supported on GNU/Linux
go1: error: ‘-fsplit-stack’ is not supported by this compiler configuration
make[2]: *** [Makefile:821: go] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [Makefile:823: gofmt] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build/gotools'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:11068: all-gotools] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/gcc-10.2.0/build'
make: *** [Makefile:942: all] Error 2
```

I am sure that my linux is gnu/linux based on my `uname -a`.
If I try to change the `--host=x86_64-slackware-linux` to `--host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`, the configuration/make output error that `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-ar` is not found etc..

This [log](https://pastebin.pl/view/0fbf9cff) might be helpful. I cannot post it here since it is too long, but it might be helpful.

Update:
Same error occurs even when I enable the bootstrap option. The only big difference I see is the time it takes to build.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to build just `gccgo`.  You can't to expect to build just an individual GCC component by itself, without building the whole suite.

Comment: @John what do you mean? Do i need to set `--enable-languages` to `all` just to compile gccgo? It sounds like it would take me a lot of hours and days just to compile one...

Comment: @John Yes I am trying to build gccgo (from gcc 10.2 source tarball)

Comment: I am trying to split gcc: example is gcc, gccgo, etc... I have already built gcc and g++ from the source tarball and I am moving on with this silly gccgo and I am stuck here...

Comment: Yes, the best approach is to configure the overall package for all the languages you want, once, and then perform the whole build in one fell swoop.  And yes, that will probably take hours to finish.  GCC is an integrated system, and although some parts are more tightly bound than others, you can't safely expect to get components that work properly together if you configure them separately.

Comment: Also, GCC is tooled to bootstrap itself, so it will be expecting to build `gccgo` via a `gcc` and `g++` built from the same source distribution and sharing the same overall configuration.  This is probably the specific issue over which your build is failing.

Comment: @John I also tried enabling `--enable-bootstrap`, still got the same error, the only difference is that when bootstrap is enabled, building takes a lot of time, which it is...

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong part of that comment.  Focus on the bit *after* the "so".

Comment: @John so meaning that if I enable `--enable-languages=c,c++,go,lto`, it will work, am I right?

Comment: I mean you *re-configure the whole source tree* with all the languages you want enabled and any other wanted non-default configuration options, and perform *a clean build of all components*.  You might be able to spread that over multiple `make` sessions to break up the build.  Safest would be to `--enable-bootstrap`, but that's probably not essential.

Comment: But overall fastest would likely be to get a complete GCC suite from your Linux distribution.  Few people build their own.

Comment: Well to be honest, can't use the gcc suite from slackware linux distribution. I need to recompile my own gcc suite, since gcc-10.2 from slackware requires newer version of glibc, which I do not want to update, probably because I want to maintain only one glibc in my system and I prefer not have multiple glibc.... and I have gcc-7.3 suite from the porteus distro...

Comment: @John Yes I will try again and tomorrow I will post an answer here if it work.

Comment: @John I got an update: The result is: It is still the same. I enable the languages c,c++,go,lto and disabled bootstrap option, which turned out, it is still the same. Got the same errors, now I am losing hope that it will build again

Comment: You likely want target `x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu`.  Blow away the entire build directory, unpack again, and start over, don't try to reconfigure in place.  There is absolutely no need to build every language frontend.